# Mostrar informacion completa (... with 21 more rows)

Tags: r, rstudio, tibble

Saludos a todos,
como puedo hacer para que se muestre todo el contenido y no (... with 21 more rows)

[image: ver la captura de pantalla]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que estas hablando de un objeto `tibble`, según la [documentación](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/vignettes/tibble.html) del mismo:

> You can control the default appearance with options:
>
> options(tibble.print_max = n, tibble.print_min = m): if there are more
>   than n rows, print only the first m rows. Use options(tibble.print_max
>   = Inf) to always show all rows.
>
> options(tibble.width = Inf) will always print all columns, regardless
>   of the width of the screen.

Para mostrar el contenido completo (no es muy recomendable) deberías setear antes que nada:

```
options(tibble.print_max = Inf)
```

Si simplemente quieres aumentar un poco el límite de corte:

```
options(tibble.print_max = 50, tibble.print_min = 10)
```

Comment: bien.. gracias...